# C++ GLSL Linking error

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm developing a 3d Engine and I got some trouble with the GLSL shader in C++.

Vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexUP;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexUV;

out vec3 UP;
out vec3 UV;

void main(){
    UP = vertexUP;//Without this line, everything works fine
    UV = vertexUV;

    gl_Position = ftransform();
 }
```

Fragment shader:

```
in vec3 UP;
in vec3 UV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D rs0;
uniform sampler2D rs1;
uniform sampler2D rs2;

void main(){
    if(UV[2]==0){//Selects between different textures
        color = texture( rs0, vec2(UV[0], UV[1]) ).rgb;
    }else if(UV[2]==1){
        color = texture( rs1, vec2(UV[0], UV[1]) ).rgb;
    }else{
        color = texture( rs2, vec2(UV[0], UV[1]) ).rgb;
    }
    if(UP[0]<2){//Test thing
        color[0] = 1.0;
    }
}
```

I want to parse the position array (Location 0) to the fragement shader so I can use it for lighting. It Compiles but linking the vertex shader gives a error:
Vertex shader(s) failed to link, Fragment shader(s) linked.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The code to load the shaders:

```
GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){
    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}
```

[image: Debug]

Comment: Is gl version < 3.0? ftransform() is no longer available since GLSL 1.40 and GLSL ES 1.0.

Comment: Do you have a `#version` at the start of the shader code? The default is version 1.10, which does not support a lot of the syntax you are using.

Comment: Print the Shader and Program logs out from OpenGL and post those.

Comment: I'm using #version 330. ftransform() isn't the problem. When I delete the UP = vertexUP; line in the vertex shader, everything works fine.

Comment: How do I print the logs? Do you mean just the debug console? The debug console says nothing more than vertex shader(s) failed to link.

Comment: glGetProgramInfoLog/glGetShaderInfoLog give access to program/shader error logs.

Comment: Yes, I've added a picture form these outputs in the beginpost but there is nothing special happening there. Just that the vertex shader failed to link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexUP;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexUV;
...
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

`ftransform()` uses the builtin `gl_Vertex`, and the GL spec requires that to alias attribute index 0, so the GL cannot assign the attribute indices without collision.

You really shouldn't mix the old, deprecated builtins with generic attributes. And if you do, you should led the GL assign the attribute locations.

Comment: +1, but, better yet, just avoid old deprecated builtins altogether. They've been deprecated since 3.0, so, what, 6-7 years?

Comment: I'm new with OpenGL and it's a little confusing because the old and the new methode. So, I also read on the internet that there is a other way to do this by using matrices or something to replace both the camera (lookAt) and the positions. Am I right? And is it lots of work to change it or maybe I can add another object buffer to contain the object positions?

Comment: Thank you, by switching to the latest openGL version with matrixes it finally worked.